# Memory issues with new game on s3

Tags: android, andengine

I am building a new game with AndEngine and for some reason i keep getting this debug statement in the Logcat:

> 01-31 21:29:50.503: I/Choreographer(697): Skipped 152 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Im not really sure what is causing this error exactly during my game. I am checking a lot of collisions, but they arent initiated until after the game play scene has started.

I also noticed on my Galaxy S3 the game causes my phone to "flicker" when swiping changing home screens and pulling down the task bar at the top.

I think this error has something to do with it, but I am not sure. What do you guys think?

Also each time the user goes to another level I initialized the collision detectors all over again. But I don't unregister or stop the last collisions that were started. I thought they would be automatically cleaned up when the new one is initialized.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

The android platform is a heavily multi-threaded environment designed to distribute the workload. Whenever assets or systems are not being used in the game, they should always be released or deleted unless there is a very specific reason why they need to remain active. Cleaning up your collision process and freeing up used memory at the end of a scene should be a standard practice for you.

The error message you post leads me to believe that the app is skipping frames to maintain a specific rate of functionality. Further research has lead me to the following link. I suggest starting the rest of your investigation here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/what-is-android-choreographer